# Saving scrapped content into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I try to count the number of words in different websites, however I get the `"TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"`. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
URL = "https://www.coach.com/shop/women/handbags/view-all"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
html_content= page.text
soup = BS(html_content, "lxml")
content = {}
try:
    text_counter = 0
    x = soup.find_all("h2")
    for y in x:
        title_length = len(y.get_text().split())
        text_counter += title_length
        content = y.findNext('p').get_text()
        content_length = len(y.findNext('p').get_text().split())
        text_counter += content_length

    t = soup.find_all("h3")
    for q in t:
        title_length = len(q.get_text().split())
        text_counter += title_length
        content = q.findNext('p').get_text()
        content_length = len(q.findNext('p').get_text().split())
        text_counter += content_length
    content["n_words"] = text_counter 
except:
    content["n_words"] = ""
```

Full trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-34168cb72272> in <module>
     26         text_counter += content_length
---> 27     content["n_words"] = text_counter
     28 except:

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-34168cb72272> in <module>
     27     content["n_words"] = text_counter
     28 except:
---> 29     content["n_words"] = ""

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `q.findNext('p').get_text()` is throwing the error -> `p` has not string content

Comment: This is because I get None, from that particular line ?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace. The error message tells us what the problem is. The stack trace tells us (and you) *where* it is. That is equally (sometimes more) important.

Comment: the `find('p')` is not enough accurate, get a better one  or filter such output

Comment: Actually I am trying to find something that would fit many websites, not just the URL, if 'p' is not find, I just want to skip it i.e. not increment the text_counter object

Comment: `if q.findNext('p').string is None: ... else: ...`

Comment: `p` is found but **some** have no string content: `<p class=...></p>`

Comment: So I tried to add the following condition but still get the same error, 
if title_length != "":
        text_counter += title_length

Comment: with `content = q.findNext('p') ; if content.string is not None: ...` I don't get any exceptions

Comment: DANGER: you define `content` as a dictionary then you overwrite it as `Tag`, `content = y.findNext('p').get_text()`

Comment: Actually, I fill the content with number of words, which supposed to be an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have two variables with the same name:

- `content = {}`
- `content = q.findNext('p')`

Just change the name of, ie, the global dictionary into smt else, `dcontent` or `word_counter`,...

```
dcontent = {} # <-- d stand for dictionary
try:
    text_counter = 0
    
    t = soup.find_all("h2")    
    # ... same

    t = soup.find_all("h3")
    for q in t:
        title_length = len(q.get_text().split())
        text_counter += title_length
        content = q.findNext('p') # <-- here the content from the soup
        if content.get_text() != '':
            content_length = len(content.split())
            text_counter += content_length
            dcontent["n_words"] = text_counter # <-- here update the dictionary
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    dcontent["n_words"] = ""

print(dcontent)
#{'n_words': 52}
```

Remark:

- use `tag.get_text() != ''` to check if the tag contains a string and not `tag.string is not None` as I said in a comment
- apply such filter always in such situations, which means also for the `h2`-case